# Phone will be hang up when i load the data from the WebService in to the tabelView

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services

```
       dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0ul);

            dispatch_sync(queue,^{

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileUrl]];

            NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
            self.time = [self DateFormatWithString:now];
            QBChatMessageCustom *customMessage=[[QBChatMessageCustom alloc]init];


            customMessage.senderID = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"jabber_id"] intValue];
            customMessage.recipientID=opponent.ID;
            customMessage.text=self.messageDBStr;
            customMessage.imageDataV=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:data];
            customMessage.datetime=[self StringWithDate:self.time];

            [self.messages addObject:customMessage];

            NSInteger currentDate = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
            if(currentDate - [self.opponent.lastRequestAt timeIntervalSince1970] > 300)
            {

                // Send push
                [QBMessages TSendPushWithText:self.messageDBStr toUsers:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.opponent.ID]delegate:self];


            }
            //[HUD setHidden:YES];
            [self SenderIDInsertDB:customMessage.senderID recipient:customMessage.recipientID TextMessage:customMessage.text DATA:customMessage.imageDataV dateFormat:customMessage.datetime];

            // reload table
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[messages count]-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
        });
```

This process will be completed after that TabelView automatically scroll down. but when when process is running at that time TabelView will be hang up.

Answer (score 0):

Any process that is related to the `UI` must be on the `Main thread`, so modify your code to this:

```
       dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0ul);            
    dispatch_sync(queue,^{

    your service call code .......... 

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[messages count]-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

            }
});
```

Comment: Good comment, but this would more likely cause a crash than a deadlock I guess

Answer (score 0):

You may go in an infinite loop when calling

`[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[messages count]-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];`

Does this scrolling of the tableView trigger the call of your method again (and thus a new scroll and so on...)?

Answer (score 0):

Try **NSOperationQueue** and **NSOperation** for multi-threading in the app i.e. view will be automatically updated when you get the response from web service.

Check Class Reference for NSOperationQueue

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html

And have a look on very useful tutorial by Ray

http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Cheers.